# Holtek keyboard controller working with reversed diode

Tags: diodes, datasheet

I am confused at a mistake I currently have in my setup. I am using this [Holtek keyboard controller](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/79209.pdf). Note how the letter Q is produced by connection between R0 and C1 (page 19). According to the datasheet, R0 is pin 6 input, and C1 is pin 20, output.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I have a matrix where the Q button is connected to the above R0 and C1, however there's also a 1n4148 diode in series with the button that is oriented from R0 to C1. I would expect this not to work, because C1 is an output pin during the matrix scan, and R1 is an input pin. The diode is reversed with respect to the flow of current (from C1 to R0). Strangely enough, it *does* work, and this really is the core of the question.

Is there something in the datasheet I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I recommend that you post the essential part of the linked document into your question so that we can understand the question on its own. That way you will get more readers and the question will still make sense when the link dies.

Comment: @Transistor it's a PDF. screenshots are going to be large

Comment: @StefanoBorini You should learn how to crop and resize graphics. Can you please add a schematic showing how the button and diode are connected?

Comment: "*I have a matrix where the Q button is connected to the above R0 and C1, however there's also a 1n4148 diode in series with the button ...*" Is this something you are making or something you have reverse engineered? Diodes are often used in keyboard and LED matrices to prevent backfeeds when two or more keys are pressed but I would expect that this controller should be able to detect and manage that. In addition, the keyboard should be able to handle multi-key presses (Shift-X, Ctrl-Alt-Del, etc.). Where did the diodes come from?

Comment: @Transistor the diodes come from the fact that I am reusing a matrix I made for a different controller, for testing purposes. Now I am creating a new matrix with the connections for the Holtek, but as I was checking my old matrix to add the diodes to the new one, I noticed that the diode is reversed for the expected need of the holtek

Comment: (1) The Holtek doesn't use diodes. There is no mention of them in the datasheet so why are you adding them? (2) The diodes will be orientated depending on whether the strobe lines are active high or active low. The datasheet does not tell us which way it works.

Comment: @Transistor I am adding them because I plan to reuse the same matrix for another controller that does need the diodes. The Holtek is for a first prototype, but I am replacing it with a controller developed in house, that does need the diodes.

Comment: The current flows from R0 to C1. The inputs have internal pull-ups.

Comment: @Dorian then it's not clear to me what they mean, and what's generally meant with I and O in datasheets. I would expect that something that is marked as O is set to zero volts, and during the scan, each pin is set to 5v briefly. On the other hand, the I pins just monitor the voltage it's on them. If what you are saying is valid, it means that the I are just at 5v, and the scan on the O pins just drives them to 0v. Is this information anywhere in the datasheet?

Comment: All inputs and outputs have pull-ups (this is specified on page 3) , this means the inactive state for input is high as you said. More , the outputs are open collector , that's why they need pull-ups and the chip doesn't require diodes.